# Можно ли так составить предложение? И правильно ли оно по смыслу?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, сложное-предложение, смысл

Евгений Эдуардович не знал, были его заболевания с рождения или стали следствием старости

Comment: Разве заболеваний в зрелом возрасте не случается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Евгений Эдуардович не знал, были **ли** его заболевания с рождения **или** стали следствием старости.*

В СПП с придаточными изъяснительными частица ЛИ используется **в качестве союза.**